# Limit number of open questions per person

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Although I'm relatively new to SE it seems there is a recent upsurge in the number of new users who ask question after question but appear to have no interest in accepting answers.

Is there a (low) limit on the number of concurrently open but unanswered questions that a low scoring user can ask? Would this feature be useful?

Typically I would expect it only to affect a new user because once such a user started accepting answers their score would begin to increase.

I'm aware that multiple downvoted or closed questions can trigger SE to [stop further questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans). This isn't what I'm looking for. Also, it's possible that leeching has been here all along and I've only just noticed, but nevertheless my question stands.

Comment: I'd be curious to know why my question has received a downvote

Comment: See "voting is different on meta" at http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta — probably someone voted -1 to indicate disagreement.

Comment: @derobert missed that; appreciated.

Comment: See this meta for how "new users" are limited: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4564/what-are-the-limits-and-restrictions-for-new-users.

Comment: @slm thank you. None of that seems to cover my suggestion.

Comment: The downvote was mine, I don't think the feature would be useful. I started writing an answer but got distracted and never finished it.

Comment: Until now, that is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having spent quite some time on this site and its review queues, I don't think there is need to worry, and that the "influx" of question dumpers is well within limits.

Not accepting answers is not a problem, although not very nice behaviour. I think the system might actually prompt you after some time if you upvote an answer without accepting it. And if the OP is bothered to write "thank you" as a comment, the upvoting/accepting is often pointed out by some other commenter.

And even if the system doesn't notice someone not accepting, some other user (like you) will, and it is perfectly OK to leave a remark in a comment to tell the poster that you noticed very few of the answers to his/her questions were accepted. Insert appropriate links  [Why is voting important](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)/[What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) in that comment, and point out that there are benefits when accepting for the poster (+2 rep) and the stimulation accepting might provide for the answerer (in lieu of any financial rewards for their effort).

Not accepting is IMO primarily a result of unfamiliarity with the system and once made aware of the workings, posters will accept (and often go back to older questions to amend their ways).

Comment: I'll try and that and see how it goes. Since this is meta I'm going to say "thank you" anyway.

Comment: If in doubt on what to do, or if you want some feedback, explain what you intend to do on chat first. There are often people around who are willing to give a second opinion, or point out where you are about to go wrong.